# Passing parameter from one stored procedure to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to pass a parameter from one stored procedure to another and trying to figure out how to put it into the string.

What I've tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
    (@ReportStartDate DATE)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE fielddate = @ReportStartDate
```

Then what I've tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc2
    (@ReportDate DATE)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery(local, 'exec dbname.dbo.proc1 @ReportStartDate="' + @ReportDate + '"')
```

but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

Then I tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc2
    (@ReportDate DATE,
     @strSQL NVARCHAR(60))
AS
    SET @ReportDate = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
    SET @strSQL = 'exec dbname.dbo.proc1 @ReportStartDate="' + @ReportDate + '"'

    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery(local, @strSQL)
```

and that causes an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@strSQL'

The proc1 allows me to run based on any date but proc2 to use last day of week plus some other stuff. I didn't include "other stuff" as I'm trying to figure out how to pass the new parameter.

Comment: The error message is because you are missing a comma between the two parameters of proc2. Actually it's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve...I'd suggest to take a look at Table Valued Functions or sp_executesql ..

Comment: Have you tried to `PRINT @strSQL` to see what your query looks like?

Comment: Peter, yes that was an oversight in posting here. Comma is in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `INSERT EXEC` in `proc2` instead of `OPENQUERY`;

```
CREATE proc2
(
    @ReportDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @t TABLE (Col1 INT);
INSERT @t (Col1)
EXEC proc1 @ReportStartDate = @ReportDate;

SELECT Col1 FROM @t;
END;
```

Note I am using a made up schema for `@t`.  You will need to create `@t` with a similar or the same schema as `table1` in your query in `proc`;

Comment: Squillman, I should have thought of that. Will give that a try in a few.

Comment: Squillman, Yes dumping the data into a temp table with an INSERT INTO works. Will just have to make note of any schema changes. Was just focused on passing the parameter.